# Getting SSL Cerificate Issue(Xamarin.ios)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am getting below error can anyone help me out this.

the certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “ciadfs1.xxxxx.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide additional details so that other users can reproduce the error you are getting.

Comment: you need to determine if you trust this server or not.  If you do, then you can implement an override for the certificate error.  But since you haven't show us any code that illustrates exactly what you're doing, we can't possibly tell you specifically how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response Jason. I am using below code in Appdelegate.cs to ignore certificate.

  System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

But still i am getting above error.

Comment: Any Help on this? still struggling with the issue.